# How to check if a javascript array of objects has every single property listed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, properties

Hello I'm trying to make a function that checks every property in a Object to see if it has all the properties listed.

For example I want to search through the objects below me

```
var exampleObj = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "Z": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "P": 2, "c": 3}];
```

and I want to know how can I build a function that will discard the ones that don't match *ALL* the properties listed below

```
var hasAllProps = ["a", "b"];
```

In the 2nd object in exampleObj, it only includes "a" but not "b" so it doesn't count so it discards it; same goes for the 3rd object. Only the first object in exampleObj passes because it had both properties; "a" and "b". I also want this function to be able to handle more than just "a" and "b" when searching through the objects as well if that makes sense.

What should I do in order to achieve this? Thank-you.

EDIT: I made a mistake on the third object as someone has commented on that. Corrected it now

Comment: Filter, where any hasAllProps value does not exist as a key

Comment: The third object has an a and a b?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please "show your work" and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your `exampleObj` with [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on `lProps`:

```js
var exampleObj = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "Z": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "P": 3}];

var lProps = ["a", "b"];

let filtered = exampleObj.filter(obj => lProps.every(prop => prop in obj))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to tell if there is an `a` property and a `b` property.

```js
var exampleObj = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "Z": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "P": 2, "c": 3}];

var hasAllProps = ["a", "b"];

var filtered = exampleObj.filter(v => hasAllProps.every(prop => v[prop]));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This fails for objects where the value is falsey like: `{"a": 1, "P": 2, "b": 0}` because `v[prop]` evaluates to false.

Comment: It is supposed to be like that, I think. It includes a but not b.

Comment: But it still has a `b` property.

Comment: You copied it down wrong. `{"a": 1, "P": 2, "c": 3}`